# readLong() return wrong value

Tags: java, io, datainputstream

I use the function of "***DataInputStream***" called "**readLong()**" to read value from a file end with ".txt".  This file was edited in advance. I want to get the correct value "123456789", but the answer is "3544952156018063160"

```
DataInputStream di = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("E:\\CMHI\\LocalHost\\src\\t.txt"));
Long res = di.readLong();
System.out.println(res);
di.close();
```

Comment: please post the actual code and not the images

Comment: You are reading a text file with "123456789" written.

Comment: Please, put actual code with the file content to easily fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

From the JavaDoc for DataInputStream

> **Returns:**
>
> the next eight bytes of this input stream, interpreted as a long.

That's not what you want, because this is a text file, not a binary.  I would recommend using a `Scanner` to read this file.  It has a `nextLong` method which does exactly what you're looking for.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("whatever.txt"));
System.out.println(sc.nextLong());
```